# Refactoring validation handling and messaging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am working on a react project that uses redux forms. I've looped through the fields to check their validation requirements if need be. This stack works well - but I know I should re-visit this to place parts inside a function

```
    if(field.validate.includes("email")) {
      //email
      if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values[fieldName])) {
        errors[fieldName] = 'Invalid email address'
      }
    }
    
    if(field.validate.includes("minLength")) {
      //minLength
      if (values[fieldName] !== undefined && values[fieldName].length < 3) {
        errors[fieldName] = 'Must be 3 characters or more'
      }
    }

    if(field.validate.includes("required")) {
      //required
      if (!values[fieldName] && typeof values[fieldName] !== "number") {
        errors[fieldName] = 'Required'
      }
    }
```

I've tried to write a function that looks like this - but I don't want to break the stack.

```
  messageHandler(field, validation, rule, message){
    if(field.validate.includes(validation)) {
      if (rule) {
        return message;
      }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: this `/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i` is very *poor* regular expression for emails ... there are people that live in other countries and use different chars than `A-Z` ... don't make people life more complicated than it should with these kind of regexp.

Comment: I just needed to get something working at the time - this solution appeared to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you're trying to validate a field's content against a set of defined rules.

To me, rules are just functions that can either be successful or not. For the sake of simplicity, let's say that if they return `null` it means that they are successful and otherwise, we'll return an error message (just a string).

```
const rules = {
  email:     value => !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(value) 
                  ? 'Invalid email address' 
                  : null,
  minLength: value => value !== undefined && value.length < 3
                  ? 'Must be 3 characters or more' 
                  : null,
  required:  value => !value && typeof value !== "number"
                  ? 'Required' 
                  : null,
};
```

Now, for each rule that we find in `field.validate`, we'll apply the corresponding rule and collect the result :

```
const matchingRules = field.validate
                        .map(formValidate => rules[formValidate])
                        .filter(x => x); // filter nullish values (rules that are not found)

const errors = matchingRules
                 .map(fn => fn(values[fieldName]))
                 .filter(x => x); // filter nullish values (successful rules)
```

Now, `errors` contains a list of strings describing how the field failed the different rules, and of course, if `errors.length === 0`, the test is successful.

You can add as many rules as you want without repeating all the `if`s.

Comment: Not sure this works as planned - errors[fieldName] = 'Required' -- is how the errors array was to be handled -- but when I look at errors in your version - it just provides ["Required"]

Comment: When I try and get the errors to come out - Invalid email addressMust be 3 characters or more -- it mashes all errors for the field at once - rather than stack them

Comment: if I do something like this -- it seems to replace the functionality --               const errorMsg = matchingRules
                             .map(fn => fn(values[fieldName]))
                             .filter(x => x); // filter nullish values (successful rules)

              if(errorMsg){
                errors[fieldName] = errorMsg.reverse()[0];
              }

Comment: `errors` is an array containing all the errors that have been encountered. If you want to display only one error, you can pick the first one.
The order of execution of the tests is the order of the array `field.validate`

Answer (score 0):

Is it acceptable in this project to bring in another lib? I like to use [joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0) for validation. Of course, it is important to understand how validation works under the hood, but it seems like you have a pretty good grasp on that.

Here's an example of how you'd implement this with your current code:

First you would define a schema, which essentially represents your ideal end-state for your filled-in form. Below, I am saying that the form values will include an `email`, which will be a required string that is at least 3 characters long.

```js
const Joi = require('joi');

const schema = Joi.object({
   email: Joi.string().email().required().min(3)
})
```

Then, when you are ready to validate the form data:

```js
const validation = schema.validate({ email: 'foo@bar.com' });
```

`validation` will contain values & errors (if there are any).

You can throw that `schema.validate` function in a `useEffect` that fires off whenever the user updates an input, or you can wait until the user is trying to submit the form, whatever your UI requires.

I like it because it is easy to read and write and it's quite flexible.

Comment: It is possible - I just didn't want to add more libs as such for now - as its already a hybrid of material ui and redux forms